# 2 parameters in backgroundSize of animate in jQuery don't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a animate to increase the background-size horizontally, keeping vertically auto when the mouse hover on it.
I tried to pass 2 parameters in backgroundSize in the animate function but this didn't work.

> Obs: I'm using jQuery 3.3.1 compressed

This is the 2 ways that I tried:

```
//First way
$('#myDiv').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundSize: "auto 130%"
        }, 450);
        $(this).clearQueue();

    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundSize: "auto 100%"
        }, 450);
        $(this).clearQueue();

});

// Second way
$('#myDiv').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundSize: "auto +=30%"
        }, 450);
        $(this).clearQueue();

    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundSize: "auto -=100%"
        }, 450);
        $(this).clearQueue();

});
```

I would like to know if there another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with css and animate the background-size on hover, for example:

```css
#kitties {
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  transition: background-size linear 450ms;
}
  
 #kitties:hover{
  transition: background-size linear 450ms;
  background-size: auto 130%; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="kitties"></div>
```